# Flash Player can not access files out of www folder

Tags: xml, flash

I have a flash player which play mp3 files from xml. at now mp3 files are downloadable with software like internet download manager. if i move mp3 files to out of www and change xml location attribute to '../mp3filename.mp3' player can not play mp3. my question are

1)  flash file can access files out of root folder

2) what is best way  to protect files from download?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flash player has to download the mp3 to play it.
If you make it available for a player to play it then by default it can be downloaded.
The only option you would have is to encrypt it somehow and use a foreign key.
Flash player security is weak at best. But security is all about how many layers you add anyway.

Comment: thank u and what do u mean when you say encrypt it and use foreign key? more description please.

Comment: Sorry, I meant a cipher not foreign key. Here is one popular form of encryption called AES which is supported in the AS3Crypto library. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard Basically, encrypting a file makes it unusable without the key.

Answer (score 1):

Flash is client side, so it only has access to whatever the client has access to.

Comment: You don't, the flash player needs access to the MP3 it can not play it if it doesn't download it.

Comment: The_asMan is correct. What is stopping the user from recording from there sound card as your "secure" MP3 plays on there machine. I bet I could download any MP3 you attempted to make secure via PHP etc. Unless you has some kind of authentication.

Comment: thank you. i know php. but how to combine php authentication code with flash application. how to let flash player download and play mp3 but user can not access mp3. do you mean use something like HTTP_REFERER or what?

Comment: @shayan not sure what you would need to do. But what I do know is that the user can just use a proxy such as Fiddler, to get the MP3 file that Flash is receiving. So there is no way to fully protect it, because the use must download it to there machine to play it anyway.